# Cannot find a way for my calculating method to output one value instead of 100

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, tostring

My problem is that I am trying to make a class of *GradeBook()* with an array of 100 grades, and with **many methods of calculating mean, mode, average, highest grade, and lowest grade of the array of 100 grades**; **then I make a client class to test all the methods in my class**. When I use my toString() method to print out a pretty statement from my client, it prints out the returned toString() 100 times. I want to print the array out with all its full length, but the calculations have to be outputted once. This means that all my calculating methods all have the same problem. I'd appreciate the help guys/gals!!!

This is in Java!

```
//find highest grade
   public int findMaxGrade()
   {
      int max = gradeBook[0]; //assume first element is the maximum

      for ( int i = 0; i <= gradeBook.length - 1; i++ )
      {
         if ( gradeBook[i] > max )
            max = gradeBook[i]; //save the new maximum
      }
      return max;

   }

//find lowest grade
   public int findMinGrade()
   {
      int min = gradeBook[0]; //assume first element is the minimum

      for ( int i = 0; i <= gradeBook.length - 1; i++ )
      {
         if ( gradeBook[i] < min)
            min = gradeBook[i]; //save the new minimum
      }
      return min;
   }

//find average
public int calcAverageGrades()
{
  int total = 0;
  int average = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < gradeBook.length; i++ )
      { 
         total += gradeBook[i];
      }
  average = total/gradeBook.length;
  return average;
}

//return assorted array
   public int[] assortedGradeBook()
   {
      Arrays.sort(gradeBook);
      return gradeBook;
   }

//find median
   public int calcMedianGrades()
   {
      Arrays.sort(gradeBook);
      int median = 0;

      median = (gradeBook[student/2]);
      return median;
   }
//find mode
   public int calcModeGrades()
   {
      final int max_range = 101;
      int[] counterArray = new int [101];
             for (int i = 0; i < counterArray.length; i++)
      {
         counterArray[i]=0;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < gradeBook.length; i++)
      {
         counterArray[gradeBook[i]]++;
      }
      int maxCount = counterArray[0]; 

      for (int i = 0; i < counterArray.length; i++)
      {
         if (maxCount < counterArray[i])
         {
            maxCount = counterArray[i];
         }
      }
      return maxCount;
    }

//return printable version of GradeBook object
   public String toString()
   {

      String returnString = "Grades: ";
      for ( int i = 0; i <= gradeBook.length - 1; i++ )
      {
         returnString += " \nThe class average is " + calcAverageGrades() + "." +"\nThe median of the gradebook is "+ calcMedianGrades() + "." + "\t" + gradeBook[i] + "\t" ;
      }
      returnString += "\n";

      return returnString;
   }
```

My result is:
Grades:
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  0
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  1
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  2
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  3
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  4
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  6
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  10
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  11
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  12
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  12
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  14
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  14
The class average is 52.
The median of the gradebook is 56.  18
//...ETC
//AND IT GOES ON TO A HUNDRED READINGS OF THIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `calcAverageGrades()` and `calcMedianGrades()`, and appending their output, *within* the `for` loop, so of course it shows up 100 times.

Take those calls and the appending out of the `for` loop.  (Leave the `gradeBook` output in.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the average and median before the individual grades loop.

```
public String toString()
   {

      String returnString = "Grades: " + " \nThe class average is " + calcAverageGrades() + "." +"\nThe median of the gradebook is "+ calcMedianGrades() + "."; 

      for ( int i = 0; i <= gradeBook.length - 1; i++ )
      {
          returnString += "\n" + gradeBook[i];
      }

      return returnString;
   }
```